# why do i get the following error even when sql alchemy is installed on the system? ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyapp = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class error_db(db.model):
    Zendesk_Ticket_No = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    Client_Name = db.column(db.String(120))
    Carrier_Name = db.column(db.String(120))
    Number_of_Records = db.column(db.String(120))
    Plan_Type = db.column(db.String(120))
    Manual_or_Macro_Error_Type = db.column(db.String(120))
    System_Bug = db.column(db.String(120))
    To_be_corrected_end = db.column(db.String(120))
    Status = db.column(db.String(120))
    EDI_File_Date = db.column(db.String(120))
    Received_Date = db.column(db.String(120))
    Completed_Date = db.column(db.String(120))
    Next_EDI_File_Due_Date = db.column(db.String(120))
    Comment = db.column(db.String(120))
    File_Worked_Upon_By = db.column(db.String(120))
    Month = db.column(db.String(120))
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

when i run this code i get the error as ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy', when i try pip install sqlalchemy, it is shown requirement already satisfied.

Comment: Because you didn't [install](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#installation) `Flask-SQLAlchemy` package.

Comment: use `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

Comment: @Corralien He did. Otherwise he wouldn't get the `requirement already satisfied` message.

Comment: @Corralien yes you are right. i installed sqlalchemy but not Flask-SQLAlchemy. Now i fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @MaikHasler. All requirements satisfied for `SQLAlchemy` not for `Flask-SQLAlchemy`

Answer (score 0):

did u use `pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy` ?
SQLAlchemy is different to Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. I didn't notice your comments. Did you check your conda environment?